# How can I duplicate the first row of a dataframe to the length of the dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I would like duplicate the first row of this dataframe but keep the index and the first column the same. I cant find a way of leaving the first column the same.

This is just a minimized example I have 1000 rows that I am working with.

This is what is tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Y':[84,94,89,83,86],'Z':[86,97,96,72,83]});

df.iloc[np.arange(1).repeat(len(df))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

This is what I am looking for

```
({'X':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Y':[84,84,84,84,84],'Z':[86,86,86,86,86]});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the columns you want, and use `.loc`:

```
cols = ['Y', 'Z']
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[0, cols].to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   X   Y   Z
0  1  84  86
1  2  84  86
2  3  84  86
3  4  84  86
4  5  84  86
```

Or, if you would rather specify the columns you *don't* want, use `df.columns.difference`:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['X'])
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[0, cols].to_numpy()
```

Comment: This works for multiple columns and I can specify which one using "difference"... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
df['Y'] = [df['Y'].iloc[0]]*len(df)
df['Z'] = [df['Z'].iloc[0]]*len(df)
```

Comment: This can work for this small example but seems like more work if I had over 20 columns. 
Thank you for the new perspective!

Comment: @lulu agreed. I thought you have only 2-3 cols

Answer (score 0):

This just works fine

```
df.iloc[1:, 1:] = df.iloc[0, 1:].values
```

Comment: Thank you, this works too, extremely simple and easy to understand.